# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodErrorat org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:52)

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

Hi I am getting the below exception while running my Spark application. My application is that to read a text file using Spark and persisting the same into Cassandra DB.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:52)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.log(CassandraConnector.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logDebug(Logging.scala:63)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.logDebug(CassandraConnector.scala:142)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:152)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$4.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:149)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$4.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:149)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:36)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:61)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:72)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:97)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:108)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:123)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:163)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:60)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDJavaFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDJavaFunctions.java:24)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.java:77)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.java:156)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.java:232)
    at Test.SparkWithCassandra.main(SparkWithCassandra.java:82)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add version numbers to improve the question. As it is, it's hard to say anything, unless someone has encountered the same stack trace. Something's wrong with your logging setup probably.

Comment: i have the same problem, running against a pseudo distributed spark vmware image 1.3.0 version and a localhost cassandra host 2.1.9 version